# In Gauss-Jordan elimination, what does it mean to 'restore' a row?

Tags: linear-algebra, gaussian-elimination

[As seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aGsT.png)

I am familiar with the elementary row operations but I've never heard an step worded in this way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never heard that word in that context before, but based on the picture, it seems to mean something like 'normalize'. After computing `row 1 - row 2`, the person multiplied row 2 by $-9/2$ in order for the entry on the main diagonal to be a 1, 'restoring' it to a form easier to work with.